# Comma in “i.e. that”

Tags: american-english, commas, subordinate-clauses, abbreviations, correlating-conjunctions

Consider the sentence:

> We claim that these sets are disjoint, i.e., ᵢ ∩ ⱼ = ∅ for different , ⩾ 0.

A proofreader (from whom I can no longer get an answer) changed it:

> We claim that these sets are disjoint, i.e. that ᵢ ∩ ⱼ = ∅ for different , ⩾ 0.

Why? What's the reason for the change? I learned that, in American English, the comma after “i.e.” is mandatory. Is this also true when “i.e.” starts the subordinate clause “that […]”?

Comment: IMO, stet. "I.e." is short for "id est," literally "that is." To my ear, "that is that..." sounds bad and I prefer your original.

Comment: @randomhead That's also what I thought, unless, of course, you read “i.e.” as “meaning”. Your reading seems more natural to me.

Comment: I don't see a problem with "i.e., that".  The two *that*s serve different functions.  "We claim X, that is, (we claim) that all Y are (etc. etc.)" sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fine with or without the "that" even though when you expand the Latin "that" is redundant. But perhaps you need neither. Do you have to remind your reader of the meaning of "disjoint". Just state the claim and go on to prove it by showing that intersection is empty.

You've asked at least one other question about a change this proofreader made.
I don't think you need to fuss all that much. Better to get a colleague who writes well to read an early draft and comment on the style.

Comment: It's either with or without the comma after i.e. but the "that" is a mistake. The point is to be consistent in usage.

Comment: @Lambie I agree that "that" is a mistake, but I wouldn't stumble over it if I read a paper where it occurred this way. I agree that comma usage should be consistent, but I probably would not notice if it were not.

Comment: Well, in a math paper, it does cause one to stumble, I'd say.

Comment: Sometimes disjoint implicitly means "disjoint if unequal". So, the reader better be made aware of what exactly is meant.

Comment: @GeekestGeek, I'm interpreting Ethan Bolker differently here.  I read "Just state the claim and go on to prove it" **NOT** as a suggestion to drop "i.e. ᵢ ∩ ⱼ = ∅ for different , ⩾ 0" but instead to drop "i.e.".  In other words, you could write, "We claim that these sets are disjoint.  ᵢ ∩ ⱼ = ∅ for different , ⩾ 0."

Comment: I don't think @Lambie is doing harm. The ideas are good. Use them when they suit. On the other point - I would see whether I could leave out X_i \cap X_j altogether in that line. Start your proof with it.

Comment: @EthanBolker Do you really think, as Lamblia, that there would be no difference in punctuation between AE and BE? Surely each institution has its rules, but there are also patterns common to BE and patterns common to AE — so common, that you can safely call then rules (with minor exceptions, if you wish). As for leaving out the math part, thanks! I see it differently because mutual disjointness has two interpretations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets) and a user might  hypothetically get confused. Of course, when low on space, I drop the math or the text to save sapce.

Comment: @GeekestGeek I'll spend time helping  improve comprehension, but not fussing about this comma.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the passage of text which you asked about:

> We claim that these sets are disjoint, i.e., that ᵢ ∩ ⱼ = ∅ for different *i*, *j* ≥ 0.

For any ***σ*** element of the set of all contemporary English sentences, ***σ*** is grammatically correct if and only if the sentence ***s*** is correct, where ***s*** is a modified copy of ***σ*** produced by replacing all instances of the sub-string "i.e." with the string "in other words" or the string "that is" modulo the fact that the first letter might have to be capitalized.

> We claim that these sets are disjoint, in other words, that ᵢ ∩ ⱼ = ∅ for different *i*, *j* ≥ 0.

Note that "We claim that these sets are disjoint" is a complete sentence. Please do not end complete sentences with a comma. Instead of a comma, use a dot, period, or full-stop (ASCII character 46).

> We claim that these sets are disjoint. In other words, that ᵢ ∩ ⱼ = ∅ for different *i*, *j* ≥ 0.

Comment: Hm. So is, in your opinion, “The hotel is closed during low season, i.e. from October to March.” wrong, and it should read “The hotel is closed during low season. I.e. from October to March.”